# Redux-api-middleware - isRSAA returning false for valid object

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-framework

I have been getting `Actions may not have an undefined "type" property.` error and on going through each line of code, I have come to this point (as shown on picture). Validation function isRSAA is returning false for right object.

Can anyone please tell me, if I am missing anything or is this a bug.

[image]

## Update 1:

on more debug: I found `hasOwnProperty` is the major cause..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem and realized I'd forgotten to add the middleware to my store as specified in the "Installation" section of redux-api-middleware's  README. Adding it fixed the issue for me!